# How to verify that prevous step was a success before moving to next step -Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

I am getting very random behaviour after running cucumber steps..I need to add a condition such that i will move to next step of cucumber only if previous steps was a success..Moreover can i set a tolerance level in my `env.rb` so that Out of 50 files,even if 10 files fails,still its a success...
for now im using

```
After('@javascript, @selenium') do
  page.has_content? ''
end
```

**...to verify between Every scenario...NOT every step.**

Comment: Is the 'random behaviour' the page.has_content? Because this could be because you check for content that is loaded asyc. To fix this use: page.should haven_content('your content')

Comment: I removed that code ...i want to set up a tolerance level for failed scenarios....any help..

Comment: You really need to understand what you describe as random behaviour. Something is doing something you don't understand. You have to search what that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to make sure the step has passed is to use rspec matches to either pass or fail your test. If you wanted the feature to fail if the content "foo bar" was not on the page you would do it like this:

```
Then /^I should see "([^\"]*)"$/ do |text|
  page.should have_content(text), "Expected to see #{text} on the page"
end
```

If you're setting a tolerance level you can use variables to keep track of the number of successes or failures. Lets say your running a feature that checks for "foo" and you're checking 50 times. In one of your steps create the variable to track the number of successes and you can use capybara to tell you if the page has what you're looking for without failing the feature if the page is missing the content:

```
Given /^Some step$/ do
  @a = 0
  if page.has_content?("foo") == true
     a += 1
  end
end
```

Then in your last scenario, check to see if a is greater than the minimum threshold

```
Then /^Last step$/ do
  @a.should be > 40, "Expected at least 40 success but saw #{a} successes instead"
end
```